# What will be GORM(grails) criteria below's SQL?

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

What will be grails GORM criteria below's SQL

Orders table:

- OrderID
- CustomerID
- OrderDate

Customer table:

- CustomerID
- CustomerName
- ContactName
- Country

> Notice that the "CustomerID" column in the "Orders" table refers to
>   the "CustomerID" in the "Customers" table. The relationship between
>   the two tables above is the "CustomerID" column.
>   Then, we can create the following SQL statement (that contains an INNER JOIN), that selects records that have matching values in both tables:**strong text**

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

the Sql will produce those data with those column

- OrderID
- CustomerName
- OrderDate

GORM MODEL:

```
class Order{

Long orderId
Long customerId
def orderDate
}

class Customer{

Long customerID
Long customerName
def contactName
def country
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and didn't work?

Comment: The SQL you show corresponds to your persistence model, which may or may not map directly to your object model.  When expressing queries with GORM, you always express queries in terms of your object model, not the persistence model.  To know for sure how to express the query, you need to show how your `Orders` class relates to your `Customers` class (or whatever classes are mapped to those tables).  Is it the case that you have an `Orders` class that has a property in it named `OrderDate` that references an instance of another class named `Customers`?

Comment: Details https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp   @JeffScottBrown

Comment: Question updated with details  @JeffScottBrown

Comment: @Tanvir. You are describing the persistence model, not the object model. GORM requires you to express your query in terms of your object model.  Is it the case that you have an Orders class that has a property in it named OrderDate that references an instance of another class named Customers? I am asking about classes, not tables.

Answer (score 0):

I am making some guesses to create an object model that matches the persistence model that you describe there.

```
class Customer {
    String customerName
    String contactName
    String country

    static mapping = {
        table 'Customers'
        version false
        id column: 'CustomerID'
        customerName column: 'CustomerName'
        contactName column: 'ContactName'
        country column: 'Country'
    }
}
```

```
class Order {
    Customer customer
    Date orderDate

    static mapping = {
        table 'Orders'
        version false
        id column: 'OrderID'
        customer column: 'CustomerID'
        orderDate column: 'OrderDate'

    }
}
```

Execute a query like this:

```
Order.findAll {
    createAlias 'customer', 'cust'
    projections {
        property 'id'
        property 'orderDate'
        property 'cust.customerName'
    }
}
```

That will result in SQL like this:

```
select this_.OrderID as y0_, this_.OrderDate as y1_, cust1_.CustomerName as y2_ from Orders this_ inner join Customers cust1_ on this_.CustomerID=cust1_.CustomerID
```

Comment: This code satisfies the request as described in the question, I am assuming that you want projections since you are retrieving `CustomerName ` but not `Country` or `ContactName`.

Comment: My order model object is like class 
`Order {
    Long customerId
    Date orderDate

    static mapping = {
        table 'Orders'
        id column: 'OrderID'
        orderDate column: 'OrderDate'

    }
}`

Comment: gorm model added in question

Comment: The model you posted in the question is inconsistent with the SQL you have expressed as a requirement.  The column names are not going to match.  Are you really just wanting to know how to retrieve the `Order` instances and their associated `Customer`?  If yes, simply call `Order.list()`.

Comment: @Tanvir Best of luck!